# Java generics: method is not applicable for the arguments (T)

Tags: java, generics

There are plenty of questions with similar error but none of them seem to be addressing my problem.

I simply want to be able to reuse same `foo` generic with various `bar` methods. What is the right way to do that?

```
public class Test {

    static public <T> String foo(T object) {
        return bar(object);
    }

    static public String bar(String object){
        return "string:" + object;
    }


    static public String bar(Integer object){
        return "integer:" + object;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(foo("blabla"));
    }
}
```

I am getting `The method bar(String) in the type Test is not applicable for the arguments (T)` compilation error.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. Why not declare two overloaded `foo` functions instead?

Comment: Naturally, because you aren't passing a `String`, you're passing a `whatever <T> happens to be`.  And `bar()` doesn't declare that it can take a `whatever <T> happens to be`.  I think maybe you want to parameterize the class, rather than the individual method?  For instance, [like this](http://pastebin.com/WUA5wGA6).

Comment: @SergeyTachenov So do you propose to write the eactly same `foo twice?`

Comment: No, I propose to rename both `bar`s into `foo`s and remove the generic `foo` because you obviously don't need it. Even if you managed to do it the way you want, you'd have a generic function which can accept only `String` and `Integer` which is no different from an overload behavior-wise.

Comment: @aroth, Thanks. Why don't I pass a `String`? `foo` receives `String` and the dynamic dispatch should forward it to `bar(String)`. No? I don't want to parametrize the class. That's an overkill in my case.

Comment: @SergeyTachenov, The logic in my actual `foo` is way more complex than in my example above. If I do what you propose I will need to move my `foo` code into all my `bar` functions.

Comment: Then your example doesn't reflect your problem fully. But anyway, in that case you just need to make it non-generic accepting `Object` and check using `instanceof` when you call `bar`. Java doesn't allow you to declare generic with `T extends String` and `T extends Integer` at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

You should update as below. Since function cannot know the type it fires an error

```
public class Test {

    static public <T> String foo(T object) {
        if(object instanceof String){
            return bar((String)object);
        }else if(object instanceof Integer){
            return bar((Integer)object);
        }
        return null;
}

    static public String bar(String object){
        return "string:" + object;
    }


    static public String bar(Integer object){
        return "integer:" + object;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(foo("blabla"));
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the point in making it generic then? Might as well just declare `foo(Object)`. As it is, it only adds confusion.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `T` is of type `Object` so that you may pass every Java Object to `foo`. The arguments of your `bar` methods on the other hand have a specifig type, in this case `String` and `Integer`. What you're trying to do is to pass an `Object` to a method expecting a `String`. Since Java cannot automatically downcast classes you get this error.

You have to cast `T` to the correct type like so

```
public String foo(Object object) {
   if(object instanceof String)
      return bar((String)object);
   if(object instanceof Integer)
      return bar((Integer)object);      
   return null;
}
```

Comment: Again, why it's even generic? Just declare `foo(Object)`.